# Security concern about Hubstaff - install a package from a sh file

Tags: bash, security, debian, debian-packaging

I was asked recently to install Hubstaff (a famous application for tracking your data, like screenshots, URLs, etc., on your computer and reporting it to your management team) on my Debian machine. After checking their download page (https://app.hubstaff.com/download) I found out that for the Linux version, I have to download a .sh file and run it (so no package manager, not a .deb file) This app tracks almost everything from my machine (https://hubstaff.com/how-tracking-works), but they don't explain how it follows them. Like they can track the URLs I visit (and no matter what browser I use), how do they do that? Are they checking my network packets?

Do you guys think is it safe to do such a thing? E.g., they say they don't track my keyboard, but they can find out if it's used or not (for idle purposes). Well, they might be right about it, but what if somebody hacks them? I feel like if I use this app, I am making my computer public. Please help me learn about it.